# Unexpected failover of RDS-MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, failover

We have a 16GB RDS-MySQL Multi-AZ instance. Of late, it has unexpectedly failed over multiple times causing the dependent application to be offline for over 15 minutes.

AWS-Support blamed it on high Swap Usage. However, the instance has failed when the Swap Usage was as low as 10 MB. We have started optimizing the queries.

Is there anything else that we can do to avoid such mishap?

===================================================================

EDIT :

We have made one observation. The CPU utilization of the instance remains fairly low. So, we presumed that the issue might be with disk access. The write-throughput is several times that of read-throughput. To add to it, Sort_merge_passes has a value of 79425(which is crazy, right ?). On going through the slow query log, it was found that there are multiple queries with ORDER BY clause not using indexes. It will take time before workarounds are found for all these queries. Can you suggest some immediate fix to overcome the    failover issue ? Should we increase the global value of sort_buffer_size ? Current value is 2MB.

===========================================================

EDIT 2 :

Below is a screenshot of the rate of change of Sort_Merge_Passes(Queries per second) as seen on RDS-Performance Insights.

[image]

As can be seen, during periods of load,the value varies from 0.5 to 1(we have observed values higher than 1 as well). A query can cause multiple **Sort_merge_passes**, 8 being the highest that we have observed.

=======================================================================

EDIT 3 :

We also found that the global status **Created_tmp_disk_tables** is increasing at the rate of approx **2-3/second**. Badly structured queries I guess.

Comment: Is there anything unusual (in the metrics or elsewhere) that you observe in the period leading up to the failover?

Comment: @AlokPatwal No, we have not being able to find any repeating patterns in the metrics.

Comment: `Sort_merge_passes` -  divide by `Uptime`.  1/second would be "high", but not high enough to be concerned with.

Comment: @RickJames The load on our server is not uniform. It varies throughout the day. So, Sort_merge_passes - divide by Uptime might not be truely reflective of the state of the database. I have added one more edit showing the change of Sort_merge_passes for the last 24 hours.

Comment: @SubrataDas - If you can spot a particular query that is doing a lot of "sort merge passes", we can discuss it.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  "8" slows down the one query, but seems to be infrequent enough not to slow down the "entire system", much less cause a failover.

Comment: @RickJames Added one more edit.

Comment: Temp tables on disk is one of many symptoms of _posibly_ badly structured queries.  Where is `tmpdir`?  How big is it?

Answer (score 3):

- Swapping is a bad symptom of over-use of RAM.
- An excessive number of simultaneous connections *may* lead to swapping.
- Very complex queries *may* lead to swapping (due to temp tables).  Let's see such queries if you have any.
- Have you changed any things in `my.cnf` (or the equivalent in RDS)?  If so let's see if you raised some values too much.
- As a quick fix (and if RDS lets you), decrase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` by a gigabyte.
- `Sort_merge_passes` -  divide by `Uptime`.  1/second would be "high", but not high enough to be concerned with.
- For deeper analysis, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis -- the GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES may find some clues; `pt-query-digest` will focus on the 'worst' queries.
- `sort_buffer_size = 2M` is fine.
- "ORDER BY clause not using indexes" - show us the queries, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: A few times, the instance failed over even when the swap usage was low. What are the other possible reasons for MySQL to fail over?

Comment: We also have a large table with FULL-TEXT index. It is queried quite frequently.

Comment: @SubrataDas - RDS has monitoring, yes?  What does it say just before a crash?

Comment: Yes, RDS has monitoring. The instance becomes unresponsive at the time of failover. There have been times where we have found ReadIOPS to go up just before the failover but no repeating patterns. 
Can you specify any particular metric?

Comment: @SubrataDas - Alas, the failovers _should not_ have happened, so I don't know what to look for.  Plan A:  Present all the graphs during the hour (or so) before a failover.  Plan B:  grab the `VARIABLES` and `GLOBAL STATUS` after it has been up for a day and hope that some clue is building up long before the crash:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: I have made an edit. Can you kindly look into it and give us your opinion ?

Comment: @SubrataDas - I added 4 bullet items.

Comment: "ORDER BY clause not using indexes" - show us the queries, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`-- There are quite a few. Shall share them on this platform one at a time as we work on it.

Comment: @SubrataDas - Yes.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`  That's usually enough to discover an improvement and/or explain why "not using indexes" is not as bad as it sounds.